# Calling Handler.Postdelayed periodically in a Thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, bluetooth, android-handler

I have a thread which listens for bluetooth serial data.

I have a method that passes data to the ui thread called: `sendData(byte[] buffer)`, which sends the data perfectly to the UI thread, which can cause it to become very slow when recieving packets at high frequency.

But i want to implement a periodic handler that calls this `sendData` method every x milliseconds, because i recieve datapackets at a high frequency.

In my Thread i called the following in the    `run()`
 method:

```
Looper.prepare;
mHandler = new Handler();
```

then i sorrounded `sendData(buffer)` ( which on its own does a perfect job) with:

```
mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                       @Override
                        public void run() {
                            sendData(tmp);
                            System.out.println("PostDelayed| "+ System.currentTimeMillis());

                             mHandler.postDelayed(this,INTERVAL);

                        }
                    },INTERVAL);
```

Interval is a pre-declared in which would be the periodic interval the method would get called.

But postDelayed's run is not getting called. I tried debugging, postdelayeds line gets called, but it exits with `'No such instance field mHandler'`.

Any ideas what to do?

Comment: Perhaps there is no such instance field as `mHandler`.

Comment: But what does that mean?

Comment: Well for a start, what is `mHandler` and where is it declared?

Comment: It is declared in the Thread and initialized in the Threads first run()

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using the ScheduledExecutorService. See the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html).

It has the scheduleAtFixedRate method, that you can use to schedule a periodic action. And in the runnable that you pass it, call mHandler.post() with your sendData(tmp) command.

Comment: I managed to implement it, but i am unable to schedule it according to my interval, which is 1000, and TimeUnit.Milliseconds in the scheduleatfixedrate method.

Comment: Have you tried to use values 1L and TimeUnit.SECONDS instead?

Comment: Yes, but no success, it gets called constantly wihtout the period.

Comment: Are you sure, you don't confuse the 'initialDelay' parameter with the 'period' in your call to scheduleAtFixedRate / scheduleWithFixedDelay ?

Comment: I pass the same parameter to both of them. I figured it may be a problem because i call it from a thread, but it was the same when called from the main activity for testing, period is not working at all...there is no delay. I need to figure out something else.

Comment: If you would post the code you are trying out, that might help.